# Ativar um objeto e desabilitar os demais

Tags: c#, unity3d

Eu estou fazendo um sistema de loja de carros na engine Unity, e preciso de um método para ativar um tipo de contorno no carro selecionado.Porém, eu preciso que o contorno dos outros carros se desativem automaticamente.
O script que eu já tenho é esse:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CarShop : MonoBehaviour {

    public string carroSelected;
    public Text velMaxima;
    public Text Acele;
    public Text cambio;
    public Text Motor;
    public GameObject capContorno;
    public GameObject copContorno;
    public GameObject viaContorno;
    public GameObject nviaContorno;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        velMaxima.text = "0 km/H";
        Acele.text = "0s";
        cambio.text = "0 Marchas";
        Motor.text = "NULL";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void capitalSel () {
        carroSelected = "Capital";
        velMaxima.text = "110 km/h";
        Acele.text = "21.90s";
        cambio.text = "4 Marchas";
        Motor.text = "Boxxer";
        capContorno.SetActive(true);
        copContorno.SetActive(false);
        viaContorno.SetActive(false);
        nviaContorno.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void copaSel () {
        carroSelected = "Copa";
        velMaxima.text = "170 km/h";
        Acele.text = "10.3s";
        cambio.text = "5 Marchas";
        Motor.text = "AP (Alta Performance)";
        capContorno.SetActive(true);
        copContorno.SetActive(false);
        viaContorno.SetActive(false);
        nviaContorno.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void viagemSel () {
        carroSelected = "Viagem";
        velMaxima.text = "170 km/h";
        Acele.text = "11.5s";
        cambio.text = "5 Marchas";
        Motor.text = "AP (Alta Performance)";
        capContorno.SetActive(true);
        copContorno.SetActive(false);
        viaContorno.SetActive(false);
        nviaContorno.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void nViagemSel () {
        carroSelected = "Novo Viagem";
        velMaxima.text = "190 km/h";
        Acele.text = "10s";
        cambio.text = "5 Marchas";
        Motor.text = "Power EA";
        capContorno.SetActive(true);
        copContorno.SetActive(false);
        viaContorno.SetActive(false);
        nviaContorno.SetActive(false);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é criar uma lista de GameObjects e dentro dela colocar o seus contornos, mas primeiro você devera deletar essas múltiplas variáveis contorno do seus atributos, o seu inicio de código devera ficar assim:

```
public class CarShop : MonoBehaviour {
  public string carroSelected;
  public Text velMaxima;
  public Text Acele;
  public Text cambio;
  public Text Motor;
  public List<GameObject> Contornos; 
  //restante do código
}
```

Para adicionar os seus contornos a lista é simples no editor do unity haverá um novo campo chamado Contornos é só arrastar todos os GameObject que equivalem ao contorno do carro para dentro, como essa novo atributo é uma lista sempre que for adicionado um elemento ele espera um próximo, mas não precisa colocar, apenas coloque os que você queira.

Agora entra a parte de desativar os contornos dessa lista, primeiro criar um metodo para desativar, nesse caso chamei de Desativar, esse metodo devera receber um GameObject para efetuar a pesquisa dele na lista que criamos anteriormente, e depois de receber esse GameObject ele identificara se existe na lista e desabilitara todos os outros que não for esse mesmo GameObject e ativara o que for o GameObject, o codigo ficara assim:

```
//metodo que ira desativar e ligar todos os contornos
public void Desativar (GameObject Contorno)
{
   //desativa todos os itens da lista
   for(int i=0; i < Contornos.Length; i++)
   {
    Contornos[i].SetActive(false);
   }
   //metodo que vasculha a lista e ativa o certo
   foreach (GameObject GOBJ in Contornos)
   {
    //se algum elemento da lista for igual ao que procura
     if(GOBJ.GetInstanceID() == Contorno.GetInstanceID() )
      GOBJ.SetActive(true);//ativa elemento igual o que esta procurando
   }
}
```